# Downgrading libc time.h in Linux 16.04

Tags: c++, linux, glibc

I am building a build environment for some cross compiled embedded sw, it is quite old, so when compiling in Ubuntu 16.04, I get a conflict, that is "redefinition of struct timeval". I was comparing time.h from old systems, I figured out timeval structure was not yet in the old libc, is it possible for me to downgrade libc?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, no, you cannot downgrade the C library in your distro.  all the other programs in your system were compiled against that new version, so trying to downgrade it will break everything (literally everything --
 like basic programs of `ls` and `mv` and such).

you can either fix your old source project, or find an old release of a distro (like Ubuntu) and install it in a VM.

Comment: I was cross compiling a powerpc embedded application, oddly enough I encounter conflicts with libc, maybe libc isn't the problem

Comment: if you're cross-compiling, then the host distro shouldn't matter.  it might if your project incorrectly does things like `-I/usr/include` ... that'd be broken regardless of the distro version.

Comment: Some symlinks probably.

Comment: if you can run the specific compile command, you can try adding -E to it and reviewing the full output.  there will be lines that start with `#` and show the absolute path to files included.  if you see `/usr/include/...` stuff, you'll want to track down where those are coming from.